# Arquivo sail não foi encontrado ( Laravel )

Tags: laravel

Já usei `composer install`, `php artisan sail:install`, `./vendor/bin/sail up -d`, `./vendor/bin/sail`, `./vendor/bin/sail build`. Todos me retornam `\vendor\bin\/../laravel/sail/bin/sail: No such file or directory`

Meu .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Meu composer json:

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.8",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^0.4.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.3",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "tightenco/ziggy": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.8",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",    
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

OBS.: Não consigo clonar o repositório git com o Docker, talvez isso esteja relacionado com o erro no sail ? Pois quando tento entrar no sail pelo terminal me retorna que o caminho não existe, mas tem a pasta no vscode e no windows

Não sei se será útil mas meu código sail:

```
dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../laravel/sail/bin" && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/sail" "$@"
```

Answer (score -2):

Se vocês está executando este comando no Windows, lembre-se que eles deveriam estar sendo executados no terminal do WSL. Lembre-se de configurar o docker antes para habilitar o WSL2.